# Import external html file with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code:

```
<input id="file" type="file">
<div id="preview">Preview</div>
```

and JavaScript Codes:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
};
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect, false);
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8te1hyv9/4/

I am trying to load an external html file from my local drive into the div id preview. Its Working fine only with image src url are on server..
How to display the image from local drive into the preview.Is this possible to convert the image url to base 64 when importing the html file.

Comment: I don't think you can import an html file that way. You could use a file upload input to get the url to an html file on you hard drive and then set that url as src of an iframe element. I think to convert an image to base 64 in the front end you need the canvas element, which will be annoying for the CORS settings.

Comment: You don`t have acces to filesystem, so you can see only choosen files.